# How to run JSP file written in text file using Apache Tomcat?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I have written some JSP in a text file and then change the extension to *Hello.jsp*. I have placed this file to

> C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\ROOT

when I am trying to run the *Hello.jsp* file using URL http://localhost:8080/Hello.jsp then the following errors comes.

> This page can't be displayed
>
> • Make sure the web address http://localhost:8080 is correct.
>
> • Look for the page with your search engine.
>
> • Refresh the page in a few minutes.

Comment: Are you able to browse to Tomcat's home page?  Use  http://localhost:8080

Comment: This error comes from your browser and means that either your server is not running, or it is taking so long that it is timing out.

Answer (score 0):

You must run your server first. It is better to use some IDE like Eclipse. It will be easier for you.

Comment: In Eclipse 1) First run Tomcat (Servers->Start) (Tomcat needs to be setup) and 2) Right click on your jsp file and select Run On Server